# openai.ChatCompletion out of date help migrate client.chat.completions

Tags: python, chatgpt-api

## Error message

ChatGPT API
Artificial Intelligence at Your Fingertips
Type your question here
Submit

Alittlebean:

What are phasers?

ChatGPT:

You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.

You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface.

Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28`

A detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742

## Usage

The full API of this library can be found in api.md.

```
import os
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(
    # This is the default and can be omitted
    api_key=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"), # put the ChatGPT Assistant API key here but do not post it here in public
)

chat_completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": "Say this is a test",
        }
    ],
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
)
```

https://github.com/openai/openai-python

ChatGPT-API-Flask-Website
https://github.com/redemptionwxy/ChatGPT-API-Flask-Website

## main.py that I need help with

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect
import openai
import os
# from openai import OpenAI

openai.api_key = 'MY_API_KEY_HERE' # put the ChatGPT Assistant API key here but do not post it here in public

# can be empty
# client = OpenAI(
    # This is the default and can be omitted
    # api_key=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY"), # put the ChatGPT Assistant API key here but do not post it here in public
#)

server = Flask(__name__)

def send_gpt(prompt):
    try:
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        # response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model='gpt-3.5-turbo',
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
        )
        return response["choices"][0]['message']['content']
    except Exception as e:
        return e


@server.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_request_json():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if len(request.form['question']) < 1:
            return render_template(
                'chat3.5.html', question="NULL", res="Question can't be empty!")
        question = request.form['question']
        print("======================================")
        print("Receive the question:", question)
        res = send_gpt(question)
        print("Q：\n", question)
        print("A：\n", res)

        return render_template('chat3.5.html', question=question, res=str(res))
    return render_template('chat3.5.html', question=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```